# What are the free livecast/livestream services with very low latency

Tags: streaming, broadcasting, live-recording, latency

What are the free livecast/livestream services with very low latency (below 3 seconds) ?

I tried YouTube Live but I couldn't keep the latency below 10 seconds.

Comment: Free + very low latency can’t exist for long in the current market. The lower the latency, the higher the bandwidth costs per gigabyte.

Comment: Can you guys please say why you have down-voted my question so I don't make the same mistakes in the future ? Thank you for your comprehension

Answer (score 0):

This first part should be a comment, but I don't have the reputation to add it as such:
Can you add more details as to your end goal is?  I suspect that you are not streaming to the general public if you need a less than 3 second latency and are instead trying to get video from one device to another.

Answer: If I am right, and you are technically inclined, look into using netcat. See [Demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e_frYStbf-M),  [Tutorial](http://www.sauravag.com/2015/02/low-latency-video-streaming-from-raspberry-pi-and-camera-module/)